# Full space on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a website deployed on AWS, I face an issue in EC2 storage.

I have space of 20G , I free up ~2G . but I couldn't now what is taking space from storage.

I execute this command to find large files
`find / -type f -size +10M -exec ls -lh {} \`

largest one was 60M, and there is no large files found.

i believe there is something taking the space but I couldn't know what is it. I couldn't find any large file in the storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "du" to find largest directories:

```
# du -mx / | sort -nr | head -10
1427    /
994     /usr
696     /usr/lib
429     /var
393     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
346     /var/lib
174     /usr/share
159     /var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps
159     /var/lib/snapd/seed
159     /var/lib/snapd
```

Also you might try to reboot to force any open but deleted files to free space.

Comment: Thanks @Tometzky
What does these number means in the result ?
When I add -h flag for du the files in results are not the same? they are also not large , largest file size 1014M which is a home directory

rebooting didn't solve issue

Comment: The `-m` flag means `--block-size=1M`, so the number will be in MiB.

Comment: thanks @Tometzky your answer was helpful